# Mat-option select set default selected option from Map

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

How can I set as default selected option the first element of the Map I'm using for mat-select? I have:

```
<mat-select formControlName="formValoreScadenzario" [(value)] ="selectedValoreScadenzario">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let scad of mappaValoriScadenzario" [value]="scad.key">
    {{scad.value}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

where `mappaValoriScadenzario` is my map. How can I set as default-selected value the first key-value element of my Map? I've only found examples with hardcoded value or with simple arrays of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should manually set it via `setValue` method of  `formValoreScadenzario` FormControl after `mappaValoriScadenzario` initialization (static init or getting data via `HttpClient` in observable subscription) like this:

```
this.formValoreScadenzario.setValue(this.mappaValoriScadenzario[0].key)
```

**UPDATE**
In case of `FormControl` nested inside `FormGroup` you can set it value like this:

```
this.ricercaScadenzarioForm.get('formValoreScadenzario').setValue(this.mappaValoriScadenzario[0].key)
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-eeqhce?file=app%2Fselect-form-example.ts)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the hint. My formControl though is inside a FormGroup so I can't access it in that way... I've tried doing `this.ricercaScadenzarioForm.value.formValoreScadenzario = this.mappaValoriScadenzario[0];` where ricercaScadenzarioForm is my FormGroup, but it doesn't work

Comment: Hi. Updated my answer

Comment: Hi, it keeps not showing the default value... I've checked and the map is full before setting the value

Comment: Misssed one thing, sorry, updated my answer - mat-select value is selected by 'value' property - 'key' in your case

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Dseaster my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

you need to fix the default selected in ngOnInit : in your .ts file,
take this example -.-,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-set-default-value-of-mat-select-when-options-are-retriev

Comment: welcome to SO. Please do not post any links as answers, rather use them as sources. There will be a time where the link won't be accessible anymore and your answer becomes useless.